# None of them is running?

Tags: technical-issues, 18-wheels-of-steel

I recently downloaded 18 wheels of steel pedal to metal but when I run the game on win 8 it shows following errors[image]

[image]
Please help me as I was not able to get anything helpful on google

Comment: This game is rather notorious for having low quality. The issue you refer to is actually listed on the "Support" tab of SCS Software's website, on the game's page. Not sure if you've read it yet or not, but for reference: http://www.scssoft.com/pttm_support.php#tabs

Comment: i tried that patch but no effect

Comment: Have you tried running the game in compatability mode? Should just need to right-click on the application, go to the "compatability" tab and try setting the compatability mode to Windows XP SP3.

Comment: nope not working same problem

Comment: Search (on F drive in this case) for a file called PRISM3D.LOG. What does that say?